# Display text below div && toggle upon click in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that is showing 3 questions that come from a database

```
 <section>
    
     {data.questions.map(text => {
            return <div onClick={handleQuestions}>{question}</div>;
        })}
     {answer}
</section>
```

I am trying to manage its state so everytime the use click the div, the answer to that question displays below that particular div.

Each question --> has an answer

```
export default function page (){

const [answer, setAnswer] = useState();

const handleQuestions = e => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.questions.length; i++) {
            if (e.target.innerHTML === data.questions[i]) {
                setAnswer(answer => {
                    return data.answers[i]
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Currently by clicking the question div, it's displaying the right answer to the question but:

1 . Answer is displaying below ALL questions rather that below that specific question:

`Desired behaviour`

- Question
- Answer
- Question
- Answer

`Current behaviour`

- Question
- Question
- Answer

2 . To add to that issue, I wanted to toggle the answer state in a way that when clicking the question div again, the answer disappeared

How to achieve the above 2 points with React/React Hooks?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are rendering the answers at the end of the section that's why it is showing at the end. Instead, you can render the answer at the same time as a question and add a hidden attribute to the answer so it won't display, and on click handler, you can add functionality to remove the hidden from the clicked div.

For ex:

```
const data = {questions: ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'], answers: ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']}

const [answer, setAnswer] = useState();

const handleQuestions = e => {
   setAnswer(e.target.dataset.id)
}

return (
  <section>
    {data.questions.map((text, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <div onClick={handleQuestions} data-id={index}>{text}</div>
          {Number(answer) === Number(index) &&
            <div className="ans">{data.answers[index]}</div>
          }
        </>
    )})}
  </section>
)
```

Here data-set and index have been used just to give an idea about the uniques id. You can use any unique value that is coming into question and use it in your code.

Comment: much better code than mine :) however, the answer isn't displaying. I can tell ```answer``` === ```id``` but still nothing.

Comment: Actually, answer and index have a different type, one was in string and the other was in number so added the type conversion.